# Memory leak in Hazelcast 3.8.2

Tags: hazelcast

We are using Vertx 3.5.0 + Hazelcast 3.8.2 (Vertx start Hazelcast in implicit mode). We are running only a single node after running for 10 days in Prod environment. We can't share the heap dump since it contains sensitive data.

I am attaching the screenshot - in case you guys can give me any pointers to debug this problem.

[image: Highest memory objects]

Comment: It may or may not be related to Hazelcast and for several reasons - without eviction Hazelcast will go OOM as its a jvm at the end of the day. Can you share Hazelcast config and also check if Vertx creates new connection for each cache operation?

Comment: We use Hazelcast API to cache lookup(IMap), why would Vertx will play a role? Also, size of objects is 6GB, which is definitely a red flag.

Comment: What do you mean size of objects 6gb - is it one object 6gb or size of total objects? I assume its latter. Whats your heap configuration? What’s your eviction policy? Nothing much can be done without seeing Hazelcast configuration.

Comment: Additionally, do you use the same connection for each cache lookup or create a new one?

Comment: We use HazelcastInstance.getMap(...) and then do #get or #put operation on it. Heap allocation is 8GB, out of which 6.2 GB taken by NonBlockingSocketWriter itself. Eviction policy is NONE and total objects in cache is around 20K and size of cache is less than 50mb or so. Cache gets invalidated every 24 Hrs - basically we destroy the old IMap and create a new one (I can explain more later if you want to know why). We let Hazelcast decide on if it needs to create new connections on every put/get operation - although I doubt that it will create new connection at every put/get operation.

Comment: @wildnez - I meant size of total objects of type NonBlockingSocketWriter. We are also wondering, lets assume that it's create a new socket for every time we do read/write, eventually old connection should be cleaned up.

Comment: Eviction = none = problem as Hazelcast does not evict or delete anything on its own. So if and when the cache is full, you will go oom.

Comment: That said, the socket writer objects are still creating doubts in my mind. Can you share the piece of code that interacts with Hazelcast - from the first line to the last line - initialising Hazelcast to cache lookup. If you create new connection for each lookup then its not automatically cleaned until it is explicitly shutdowns.

Comment: Sir! We have only 20K objects in cache and size of those objects is only 50MB. How come Eviction = none will cause OOM? I will put an example on Github on what we are doing. We also found out that this particular customer of our who reported OOM issue was using just a single node, so there won't be any network call in that I case.